# How to configure multiple emails in laravel project on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, email, shared-hosting

Good day. I have a website that I am hosting on a shared hosting plan. Now, I already set up two emails support@website.com and sales@website.com. I am confused as to how I am going to set up my .env file for both mails.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=shared_host_name
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mail@sharedhost.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Will I do this twice? or I put the two mails for the username?

Comment: you just need to manipulate the configuration on code to change what you need.
\Config::set('....','...'); based on your need

Comment: I don't get you.

Comment: My question is, do you just want to switch between emails only? Or you want to change the mail settings too?

Comment: Look, If you want to have multiple configuration
In the function you want to use different driver
then in the function write \Config::set('mail.driver','your driver name');
and same for the rest

Answer (score 0):

I would change the [Mailer Configurations](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/mail.php#L18)

For example:

```php
    'mailers' => [
        'support' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME_SUPPORT'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD_SUPPORT'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],
        'sales' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME_SALES'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD_SALES'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],
```

In you `.env` something like:

```php
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=shared_host_name
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

MAIL_USERNAME_SUPPORT=mail@sharedhost.com
MAIL_PASSWORD_SUPPORT=password

MAIL_USERNAME_SALES=mail@sharedhost.com
MAIL_PASSWORD_SALES=password
```

And to use a specific mailer config:

```php
Mail::mailer('sales')
    ->to($request->user())
    ->send(new OrderShipped($order));
```